# Load external data stored in xml file

Tags: jquery, spring, model-view-controller, jsp

I have an application using jquery, jsp, spring mvc. currently I load data stored in xml files which are in /WEB-INF/resources/data/...xml: For that in a JQuery I'm doing this:
$('#contents').load(contextPath+'/resources/data/data1.xml', ...)

After that my jsp is fed with xml content. fine.

Now: 
I would like to put the xml files on the disc of my server. So it will be available through a path: like /myWorkPlace/data/data1.xml

The reason is: I would like to change the XML content without redeploying the application.

Then How could I load these xml content ?

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX systems you might try to create symbolic link to the file outside application scope. But it's ok only for development on single machine, it would get at least difficult if you use multiple servers, and impossible if you are going to use different hosting platforms.

The proper way would be to bind Apache for handling static files with application server (for example jBoss) for everything else using AJP (you might want to google for details about particular AS). For running example, take a look at Bitnami jBoss stack (http://bitnami.org/stack/jboss) - it's built that way.